# allow access file and deny downloading using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, flash

i'm using Apache and i have a sample web folder (on my Localhost) like:

```
http://localhost/swfview/
```

In the folder, the files will be:

```
 swfview(Folder)
 |-- index.php
 |-- flash(Folder)
    |-- a.swf
    |-- .htaccess
```

The "index.php" will simply include:

```
<html>
<body>
  <embed  id="" src="flash/a.swf">
</body>
</html>
```

i want to write .htaccess file in the folder to do these

1.When i run the website at http://localhost/swfview, there will be simply showing the flash `a.swf' on the index.php page.

2.when type http://localhost/swfview/flash in the address bar user cant access the files files in the flash folder.

3.and also user prevent download swf file 
specially when accessing the index.php file browser like firefox can download have facility to download files going by (option-->page info --> media tab)

Comment: This is not possible, short of adding some really complex DRM.

Comment: You can't prevent downloading in a simple way. Users need it to be able to download it, otherwise the embed won't work. You can only restrict users from viewing the directory contents of the flash folder. See http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/securing-your-content/ for example.

Comment: may be this will help you: [How to restrict a Flex application to only run from my website](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1231847/4381432) In this way the downloaded file will be useless.